# groovy GroovyTestCase shouldFail exception message

Tags: unit-testing, exception, groovy

I have a method that throws exception in some cases. My unit test:

```
class Bob extends GroovyTestCase {

    void testClusterInvalidSomeParameter() {
        Abc abcClass = new Abc(2, 0)
        shouldFail {
            abcClass.calculate()
        }
    }
}
```

`If second parameter == 0`, then method throws exception: `"Parameter cannot be null"`. How can I test that it throws exactly this exception?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**`shouldFail()`**](http://groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/GroovyTestCase.html#shouldFail(groovy.lang.Closure)) and [**`shouldFailWithCause()`**](http://groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/GroovyTestCase.html#shouldFailWithCause(java.lang.Class,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) returns the cause/message of the exception. If the message/cause is set then, you can use the assertion as below:

```
class Bob extends GroovyTestCase {

    void testClusterInvalidSomeParameter() {
        Abc abcClass = new Abc(2, 0)

        String message = shouldFail {
            abcClass.calculate()
        }

        assert message == "Parameter cannot be null"
    }
}
```

A better test would be to also `assert` the type of Exception thrown:

```
String message = shouldFail( XyzException ) {
    abcClass.calculate()
}
```

Comment: By the way: junit4 version of shouldFail (`groovy.test.GroovyAssert.shouldFail`) differs from junit3 (`GroovyTestCase.shouldFail`) version. It returns the exception instead of the message.